# What is the property "range delta" for a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive

My Windows 7 alerts errors in my hard drive every time I start the computer. I used HD Tunes to check for errors and got nothing wrong except one value "range delta" is approaching 0. I think it's one of the S.M.A.R.T things, but not sure what is actually means. Do I need to change a hard drive for now?

Answer (score 0):

Randge Delta is not one of the [S.M.A.R.T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes, wikipedia has a full list of each attributes.

As for the range delta, it is the difference between the least worn and most worn block on the hard disk, a value close to 0 means there isn't a big difference, this is a good thing.

*Note for solid state memory its the difference between the most warn and least warn Flash Blocks :)

If you want to see your hard drive's S.M.A.R.T. data i recommend using Everest Home Edition, it tends to be the most trusted tool out there.